Multicore Processor False Sharing Problem
Suppose that you have a multi-core processor where each core has a private cache with 64-byte blocks. Suppose that two processors PA and PB perform the following operations on memory blocks. We used the notation B_I(J-K) to indicate an operation on byte range J-K of block I. Identify those operations that lead to false sharing.
PA writes B_0(0-3) and PB writes B_0(4-7)
PA writes B_1(60-63) and PB reads B_1(8-11)
PA writes B_0(0-3) and PB reads B_1(8-11)
PA writes B_0(0-3) and PB reads B_0(16-19)
PA writes B_0(0-3) and PB reads B_0(2-3)
I know for a fact that the first operation does result in a false share. However, I'm unsure of the remaining 4.

Was that first one supposed to be writes/reads instead of writes/writes?  And any time two processors access a single block, there's a conflict; the byte numbers are irrelevant.

You need to check if they are on the same cache line(if 2 address is 64+ bytes farther then they cannot cause a false-sharing miss)
